# gorm don't find a column field with quotes

Tags: go, go-gorm

Here is my code :

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
  "time"
    "fmt"
)


func (Rank) TableName() string {
    return "Score_rank"
}

// Overriding Column Name
type Rank struct {
    Id   int64     `gorm:"column:id"`
    DateCreation    time.Time `gorm:"column:dateCreation`
    Score         time.Time    `gorm:"column:score"`
    Rank         time.Time   `gorm:"column:rank"`
    ReceiverId       int64     `gorm:"column:receiver_id"`
}


func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user=toto dbname=repsys password=akaburrules")
    defer db.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    defer db.Close()


    var rank Rank
    //db.First(&rank)
    db.First(&rank)
    fmt.Println(rank)
    fmt.Println(rank.ReceiverId)
    fmt.Println(rank.DateCreation)
}
```

The output is :

```
{3 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 2018-06-23 13:34:35 +0200 CEST 2018-06-23 13:34:36 +0200 CEST 3}
3
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

but the problem is that the rank.DateCreation is false :

[pgadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSPBu.png)

i don t understand why i have : 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC for dateCreation. It seems to be also a blank value

the value should be : 
2018-06-23 13:34:11+02

here is the pg admin view of my db
[pg admin view of my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tYAE.png)

edit :

Here is the script of creation for my db :

```
  "dateCreation" timestamp with time zone,
  score timestamp with time zone,
  rank timestamp with time zone,
```

the problem may be :

> "dateCreation" timestamp with time zone

, the quote.

So how to map this field witth the quote ?

Thanks and regards

Comment: seems to be a syntax error:
DateCreation    time.Time `gorm:"column:dateCreation`

Comment: right after DateCreation you are missing "

Comment: I agree with @archit gupta, you have a syntax error in your DateCreation. It is missing closing (").

`gorm:"column:dateCreation` should be `gorm:"column:dateCreation"`